# Rating Stars in R shiny app

Tags: r, semantic-ui, shiny

I am trying to add some elements to my shiny app to make it look better.
Therefore, I am using the new `shiny.semantic` package which allows to add semantic UI elements in an easy way.
One finds examples for shiny semantic elements here:
http://demo.appsilondatascience.com/shiny.semantic/components/

I wanted to add a rating stars UI with the following code:

```
library(shiny)
#devtools::install_github("Appsilon/shiny.semantic")
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- function() {
  shinyUI(
    semanticPage(
      title = "My page",
      suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
      div(class = "ui star rating")
    )
  )
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui = ui(), server = server)
```

Unfortunately, the rating stars are not appearing in the app. Is there another way to add such rating stars to shiny apps?

Comment: Do any of the other elements work? For example `div(class = "ui right labeled input", tags$input(type = "text", 
    placeholder = "Enter weight..."), div(class = "ui basic label", 
    "kg"))`?

Comment: Yes most of the elements of the link I shared in the question are working. Did not test all but rating stars so far the only one that did not work. Have you tested rating element?

Comment: It looks like the [ratings.js](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.semantic/blob/develop/inst/semantic/components/rating.js) file is supposed to go through and append the icon elements to each div with the class `ui star rating`, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Might want to file an issue on their Github. In the mean time, change your `div` code to `div(class = "ui star rating",
          tags$i(class='icon'),
          tags$i(class='icon'),
          tags$i(class='icon'),
          tags$i(class='icon')
      )` and it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize with Javascript code

***ui.R***:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

shinyUI(semanticPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  div(class = "ui star rating")
))
```

***server.R***:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
jsCode <- "
$('.ui.rating')
  .rating({
    initialRating: 3,
    maxRating: 5
  })
;
"

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  runjs(jsCode)
})
```

Comment: Do you also know how to set initial Rating manually for an element? I tried div(class="ui rating, data-rating="2") but did not work in shiny..

Comment: @R_FF92 `div(class = "ui star rating", "data-rating"=3)` works but you still need the js code `$('.ui.rating')
  .rating({})`

Comment: Thank you...again I have to ask how I can bring this star rating now in renderUI ? Do I have to write some jquery code directly in renderUI?

Comment: @R_FF92 Hmm the key point is to run the JS code after the ui is rendered. I can't say without attempting. Maybe you should open a new question, the solution could depend on the specific situation. Instead of using renderUI, you could enter `div(class = "ui star rating", "data-rating"=3)` and then initialize the rating in an observer.

Comment: I opened new question with some example code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057621/shiny-semantic-ui-elements-in-renderui

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent how do you pass `inputId` to `div(class = "ui star rating")`?

Comment: @jpinelo `div(id="iinputId", ...)` or I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use my `shinyRatings` package. https://github.com/shahronak47/shinyRatings

```
#Installation of the package from Github
#devtools::install_github('shahronak47/shinyRatings')

library(shiny)
library(shinyRatings)
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- semanticPage(
  shinyRatings('star'), 
  textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({paste("No. of stars : ", input$star)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]