# Shiny semantic Ui elements in renderUI

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, semantic-ui

This question is based on my previous about adding ui semantic elements in shiny apps. Here the links, to recent questions:

[Rating Stars in R shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893336/rating-stars-in-r-shiny-app/44999339?noredirect=1#comment77086627_44999339),
[How to flip up shapes in shiny by clicking a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988097/how-to-flip-up-shapes-in-shiny-by-clicking-a-button/44999218?noredirect=1#comment77071387_44999218)

I am able to display rating stars and shapes if they are constructed directly in UI.R. However, I need them within a renderUi, since I have a login page and use observe for the UI.

Here example code:

Ui.R:

```
shinyUI(semanticPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  ,uiOutput("test")))
```

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(highlighter)
jsCode <- "
$('.shape').shape();
$('.ui.rating') .rating({});
"


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    runjs(jsCode)
    output$test <- renderUI({
      tagList(
      div(class="ui shape",
          div(class="sides",
              div(class="ui header side active","This side starts visible."),
              div(class="ui header side","This is yet another side"),
              div(class="ui header side","This is the last side"),
              div(class="ui header side",div(class="ui star rating"))
          )
      ),
      tags$button(id="test", class="ui button", "Flip", onclick="$('.shape').shape('flip up');")
      )
    })

})
```

Problem is, that rating stars are not displayed in the app, if I put them inside a render UI. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
  output$test <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(class="ui shape",
          div(class="sides",
              div(class="ui header side active","This side starts visible."),
              div(class="ui header side","This is yet another side"),
              div(class="ui header side","This is the last side"),
              div(class="ui header side",div(class="ui star rating"))
          )
      ),
      tags$button(id="test", class="ui button", "Flip", onclick="$('.shape').shape('flip up');"), 
      tags$script(HTML("$('.ui.rating').rating({});"))
    )
  })
```

Comment: PS: note that the JS code `$('.shape').shape();` is useless, you can remove it.